# Safari dialoge box is not opening in automaton browser instance

Tags: macos, selenium, automation, safaridriver

I am automating an application on safari browser using Selenium and Java.

For uploading a file on safari browser, I need to click on upload button.

But the dialog box for selecting a file is not showing in Automation browser instance.

While in regular safari browser (other than automation instance), I can see the dialog box for the same page.

What's the reason for dialog box not opening in safari automation instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Apple webkit's issue. Reference - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5236

Solution is to either downgrade Safari version and use Selenium's safari driver or wait for Apple webkit to fix this issue.